# Is there support for Unicoins in the StackExchange API?

Tags: support

I would like to integrate Unicoins into my StackExchange Palm OS app.  I'm using API v2 but I don't see any documentation.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-no-longer-beta/

Is this possible or is there planned support for Unicoins?

Comment: Yes! It's available only to those who have used bacon to purchase Unicoins.

Comment: That is what I suspected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Unicoins seem to have been retired for now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins), and the current revision of the API (2.2) does not support anything even remotely currency-related, unless you count Bitcoin Stack Exchange. (We can still dream about the inclusion of Unicoins in 2.3 or 3.0, though.)